# How can I set a a4 landscape page with crop marks?

Tags: geometry, landscape, crop

I need to set a a4 page in landscape mode with crop marks in every corner of the page. I used the geometry package with the following values,

```
paperheight=22.76cm,
paperwidth=31.46cm,
a4paper,
landscape,
layoutoffset={1cm},
hmargin={0.15cm,0.15cm},
vmargin={0.15cm,0.15cm},
nomarginpar,
showcrop,
includeheadfoot
```

But only one crop mark in the upper left corner of page appeared. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making contradictory statements:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  paperheight=22.76cm,
  paperwidth=31.46cm,
  layoutwidth=29.7cm,
  layoutheight=21cm,
  layoutoffset={1cm},
  hmargin={0.15cm,0.15cm},
  vmargin={0.15cm,0.15cm},
  nomarginpar,
  showcrop,
  includeheadfoot
}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\kant
\end{document}
```

With `layoutwidth` and `layoutheight` we specify that the "inner" size is A4 landscape.

Comment: In a test here I had to interchange the measures for paperheight and paperwidth, too: `paperheight=31.46cm, paperwidth=22.76cm`.

Comment: @Speravir You probably used `landscape`

Comment: Oh yes, I’ve forgotten to remove it. Thanks!